# Does Unknown's special ability still work after revealing?

Tags: shadow-hunters

Unknown's special ability is

> Deceit: When given a Hermit Card, you may lie about your identity to trigger the card or to say "nothing happens". You do not have to reveal your identity to use this Special Ability.

After Unknown has revealed, can he still lie about the effect of a Hermit Card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our group I must admit we never thought of giving Hermit Cards to revealed characters. We took the description in the rules too seriously I suppose:

> Hermit Cards help you to identify the characters belonging to the other players.

This being said, a quick check confirms that the rules don't mention you **must** give it to an unrevealed character. So the revealed *Unknown* can be given a Hermit Card and he can lie to choose the effect he wants...

Note that only the player who gives the Unknown the Hermit Card will actually know that the Unknown lied as the rules also say:

> The player who drew a Hermit Card and the player who was given the Hermit Card are not allowed to tell the other players what was written on the card.

Comment: Yeah, nothing in the rules says that you can only give Hermit Cards to revealed players. I tend to agree with you, though our group ruled it the other way at the time, i.e. Unknown could not lie once revealed.